# jquery convert alphabet of a given paragraph to numbers and calculate them

Tags: jquery

for example a = 1, b = 2, c = 1

so that <p> cab </p> would be a sum of 4!

and then update that number into a span after the paragraph,

Preferably I would like to use it on a contentEditable=true (or textarea) and have it update automatically on key up so live or bind.

what would be the best way to start ?

& Happy new year!

---

have started with

`$('p').append('<span></span>');
$('p').live().each(function(){$(this).hover(function(){$('span',this).replaceWith('<span>' + ($(this).text().length - $('span',this).text().length ) + '</span>')})})`

and am stuck at figuring out how to update newly added paragraphs to this p which is a contenteditable = true

havn't started on the a=1 b=2 code part yet

Comment: @webestdesigns Then this is not the place for your question.

Comment: I don't think it is too complex. But people will be more helpful if you show you have done some decent effort in trying to get this to work. Or if you have some specific question in stead of `canihaztehcodez`.

Comment: The best way to start is to put some effort to solve your problem by yourself, then come to StackOverflow and show us what you have done so we can help you. You'll see it's not too complex to follow the rules of this site.

Happy New Year!

Comment: ok thanks for the message. sorry for wasting your time, all I asked for was a direction. But I will listen to you all and start myself!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("textarea").on("keyup", function(){
    var val = $(this).val(),
        str = val.toUpperCase(),
        len = str.len,
        sum = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var num = str[i].toCharCode() - 64,
            sum += num;
    }
    $("#output").text( sum );
});
```

Comment: thanks for a good sense of direction